# How do you find every self-destructed contract using geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, selfdestruct, chaindata, data

I'd like to use my go-ethereum node to find every self-destructed contract in the history of Ethereum and get their addresses.

What is an efficient way to do so?